# Why is the Bulma tooltip not working on this span?

Tags: tooltip, bulma

I am using Bulma and cannot get the tooltip to work on a span, can anyone see what the issue is please?

```
<span class="favicons fa-layers fa-fw tooltip is-tooltip-bottom" data-tooltip="test">
    <i class="fas fa-pound-sign"></i>
    <span class="fas fa-caret-down" data-fa-transform="shrink-7 right-10"></span>
</span>
```

I am expecting to see a tooltip but am not

Answer (score 1):

It seems you use [bulma-tooltip extension](https://wikiki.github.io/elements/tooltip/). 
Is extension correctly installed?

Take a look on the docs to see how to install and use it in your site:
https://wikiki.github.io/#installation

If you use webpack, you can add this extension with npm:
`npm install bulma-tooltip`